# What is the Java equivalent of this Scala code?

Tags: java, scala

What is the Java equivalent of these traits in Scala?

```
trait Visitor {
  type X
  type S<:Strategy
  type R[v<:Visitor] = (S{type X = Visitor.this.X;type V=v})#Y
}

trait Strategy {
  type V<:Visitor
  type X
  type Y
}
```

I translate the `Strategy` trait to:

```
public interface Strategy<V extends Visitor<?, ?, ?>, X, Y> {

}
```

I try translating trait `Visitor` to:

```
public interface Visitor<X, S extends Strategy<?,?, ?>, R ?????> {
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to understand/translate type `R` in the `Visitor` trait. What is a similar Java equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is impossible to write an equivalent in Java, its type system is just not sophisticated enough. `R[v <: Visitor]` is a higher-kinded generic type and it would require something along these lines:

```
interface Visitor<X, S extends Strategy<?, ?, ?>, R<? extends Visitor<?, ?, ?>> extends ...>
```

but this is not possible to express in Java because it does not have higher-kinded types in generics. And that's not even mentioning that `(S{type X = Visitor.this.X;type V=v})#Y` bit which is a structural type with refinement (as far as I remember, it is called like this). I don't know any other language except Scala which has such thing.

Comment: Maybe we could define third `interface R<.....>` and use this in the Visitor generic?

Comment: I doubt it, it would be a completely another class then. The above piece of code in Scala produces nothing except `Visitor` and `Strategy`. Also I don't think it is possible to encode default values for abstract type members (maybe something based on partial generics specialization would work, like `interface A<X, Y> {}; interface B<Y> extends A<Concrete, Y> {}`, but I doubt it too). Either way, Java type system is just not powerful enough to express these concepts.